# How to add background image in section of html by using css?

Tags: java, html, css, web-deployment, web-development-server

I am trying to add a background image in my section tag but it is not working.
I have taken the correct file also still it's showing nothing in the webpage and exactly the same code I have seen someone has written in his code on youtube and that worked

```css
*
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.header
{
    height: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.6),rgba(0,0,0,0.6)),url(images/taj-mahal.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Visit India</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
</head>
<body>
    <section class="header">
  <div class="container">
            
    </div>
        </section>
 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you explain what exactly this has to do with Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enclose the path to image in quotes

```
 background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.6),rgba(0,0,0,0.6)),url('images/taj-mahal.jpg');
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have some contents for container, the background image will be loaded. Now the the height of ".header" section is zero. 
Or you can change height: 100% into height: 100vh to check the background image showing.

```css
.header
{
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.6),rgba(0,0,0,0.6)),url(images/taj-mahal.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add single quotes around the path to the image